# Further help needed to connect Samsung T7 SSD to new Mac mini

Tags: ssd

Read and copied to Notes the [resolution](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/423227/samsung-portable-ssd-t7-not-recognized-in-big-sur/423228#423228) that user [davewy](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/111030/davewy) offered to the [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/423227/samsung-portable-ssd-t7-not-recognized-in-big-sur) asking for help on same issue. I tried all other solutions offered by YouTube videos, and they failed. How do I implement these "sequence of steps"?

Last Mac was a Power Mac some 10 years ago. Have had Windows based HP since. Switching back to Mac, but really need this 2 TB portable SSD drive connected. What do I click on, and where do I implement these steps?

Does each get copied and pasted somewhere then executed?

Comment: What question are you writing about

Comment: @mmmmmm: Fortunately, [davewy](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/111030/davewy) has had limited Ask Different experience.